# Configuring Primary/Standby Server for Streaming Replication in postgres

Tags: postgresql, replication

I want to setup streaming replication for my application. I'm following postgres
official streaming replication. I am clear with every setting except
`archive_command`  and `restore_command` setting.

Especially with `%p` and `%f`. Now I'm configuring primary server: I had given the following location

[image: Location Specified]

But to my wonder, archive logs are getting stored in the below location:

[image: Location of ArchiveLog files]

Why is this happening? Can anyone correct me where am I going wrong?

Comment: With _streaming_ replication you don't need `archive_command` or `restore_command`. Also: Postgres 9.1 will be unsupported in 2 months. You should _really_ plan an upgrade to a up-to-date version.

Comment: Try doubling the backslashes, i.e. use \\ instead of \ (not sure why this could make a difference, I'm just a Windows ignorant guessing). @a_horse_with_no_name: PostgreSQL 9.1 has been out of support for almost a year now.

Comment: Can you check whether archives are also being stored in the archive folder. Searching through postgres logs will also tell you what is happening behind the scene.

Comment: @ Lohit gupta -- I can't find any logs in archive logs folder. But i proceeded to configure standby server anyways as I am getting archive files generated. But the after specifying restore command I am unable to start standby server. I cannot figure out why the standby is not starting?